# Nginx proxy pass source ip

Tags: nginx, proxy

Is it possible to specify which source IP address nginx will use when connecting to upstream?

Basically something like `tcp_outgoing_address` in squid.

**Edit**
Goal is to have something like `tcp_outgoing_address $server_addr;` under location or server block in nginx configuration, so same ip would be used connecting to upstream as `$server_addr` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [proxy_bind](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_bind) directive for that.

Comment: Is is possible to somehow use $server_addr variable? `proxy_bind $server_addr` results in: `invalid address "$server_addr"`

Comment: To answer my own question about variables: they are supported from version 1.3.12.